# generalise and log SQL query in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, jdbi

I am using JDBI to query MySQL in my java app. I want to log the metrics around the queries that are being performed on the app such as time spent by a query, the number of times a query was executed, time spend to obtain handle etc.. Although most of my queries are performed through a prepared statement, I have some queries where I pass the parameters in the query as part of SQL string. for example

```
select * from products where category in ('a', 'b', 'c') and id = :id;
```

JDBI logger outputs it as

```
select * from products where category in ('a', 'b', 'c') and id = ?;
```

it becomes very hard to group multiple queries to analyse it. Is there a library in java which can help me generalise such queries to like

```
select * from products where category in (?) and id = ?;
```

or maybe

```
select * from products where category in (?, ?, ?) and id = ?;
```

P.S. I know it is a really bad design to concat a string in SQL queries.

Comment: "concat a string in SQL queries." is by definition not a bad design..Concatting a string into a SQL query which values are controlled by a user is.

Comment: If you want to log MySQL queries and timings you need to program your own acces layer.. And program every query to use it.

Comment: Not a bad desing per se. Empirically speaking it's a bad design only 99% of the time. ;)

Comment: Jdbi 2 has a `TimingCollector` interface, whereas Jdbi 3 has `SqlLogger`. Both of these can be configured globally on the JDBI singleton.

Comment: @qualidafial yeah I am using `SqlLogger` and the output query is `select * from products where category in ('a', 'b', 'c') and id = ?;` because i am concatenating string `'a', 'b', 'c'`. I am looking some way where I can parse and replace the concatenated string with a generic placeholder like `?`

Comment: Another option is to simply log which SQL Object method is being invoked. This is accessible through `StatementContext.getExtensionMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there are two approaches, both of which seem to meet your desires:

- The Slow Log : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html
- The `performance_schema` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html

I think both will do `in (?, ?, ?) and id = ?`, and they use that as a "digest" of the query to summarize similar queries as to elapsed time, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, @rick-james both slow log and performance schema is great but visualising it becomes a pain. I was thinking of something inside my app itself so that it can post to statsd and I can visualise it easily.